# select for update waiting for network operation?

Tags: sql, database, multithreading, postgresql

I'm implementing a online shop.

I'm wondering if it is ok to use `select for update` locking for an order record.
Following are the order state changes that I consider locking.

- payment processing: buyer pays for the order, order goes from `waiting-for-payment` to `paid`
- order cancelling: buyer or seller cancels the order
- order confirm: seller confirms the order so that buyer can't cancel the order anymore

For instance, when buyer cancels an order, and seller confirms the order.
Without locking, it is possible that buyer performs the cancelation, and seller confirms the order at the same time.
But with locking, either buyer cancels or seller confirms.

So far so good, my question is this: locking an order instance waiting for network operation (payment processing) would be too big performance overhead even though it's only a row in the table?

I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Database Locking mechanism to implement Business Logic. That is a bad idea.

Instead introduce a [Transaction State] flag field and analyse it to apply Business Logic. That would enable flexibility in business scenarios when you can have multiple different Transaction States and complex Business Rules applicable for each of the states.

Better still use Transaction Processing History table with full log of Transaction States over time.

**Update**:
The status should change only if it is consistent with the history. If the payment has failed there is no point in marking the order payed and then rolling it back.

For every change there should be a list of requirements verified before the action takes place. Check there are items in the basket **and** customer confirmed delivery address **and** total price is greater then the discounts **before** requesting payment.

There are infinite scenarios of order state change and having a separate code for each state that would also include the entire history is impractical. Order can become available for dispatch after payment confirmation **or** customer return **or** replacement on non-delivery **or** pre-ordered items arriving from the supplier **or** any number of other situations.

Better keep track of order state full history for each order to analyse business scenarios and choose the best next action accordingly.

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. `Better still use Transaction Processing History table with full log of Transaction States over time` Can you provide me a link where I can understand this statement better?

Comment: My guess is that, you create history of state changes. and after you change status, you look at the previous state change and raise error and roll back if the current status change is not valid from the previous state.. Wonder how I could  use the history table..?